# How to filter-out file name from SRC?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have assigned the image path to variable as follows.

```
var path = $(this).closest(".uploaded-img").data("src");
```

`var path` give full path of a image like `assets/uploads/image1.png`.

I need to get only image name. (with extension and without extention). How I do this using jQuery?

Comment: You can do this in vanillajs: `var file = path.split('/').pop();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var path = $(this).closest(".uploaded-img").data("src");
var imgName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, path.length);  // For image full name
var imgName2 = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, path.lastIndexOf("."));  // For image name without extension
alert(imgName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this snippet:

```
String.prototype.filename=function(extension){
    var s= this.replace(/\\/g, '/');
    s= s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('/')+ 1);
    return extension? s.replace(/[?#].+$/, ''): s.split('.')[0];
}
```

and then:

```
path.filename();
```

to get the filename without extention
or:

```
path.filename(true);
```

to get the filename with extention